# DirectShow - how to save a buffer of recorded audio from AVI Mux filter instead of writing to file

Tags: winapi, audio, directshow

I am writing a small DirectShow application in C++,

and i'm have a lot of trouble fetching the data of the recorded audio.

What i'm trying to achieve :

**Microphone->Avi MUX filter->Data buffer->send buffer to server-> write data to an Avi file**

How can this be done ? How can I fetch the raw buffer from the Avi Mux filter?

Help would be much appreciated

My current filter graph is built as follow, and it works:

**Microphone -> Avi MUX filter -> File writer**

This filter graph flow works fine, and i'm able to hear the recording.

Comment: You tagged this C++ so there's no way to answer it without seeing some C++ code.

Comment: Is it possible to utilize the **dump** filter like **Microphone->Avi MUX filter->dump filter** which [get the media sample data in the overriden Receive](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/dump/dump.cpp#L319)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lack one important aspect. Are you going to send the data to server as content is being generated, or you want to send on completion and just bypass disk file creation.

In either case you need an equivalent replacement for file writer filter, with your custom filter. SDK Dump Filter Sample [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/dump-filter-sample), [2](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/tree/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/dump)] might be a good starting point. You will have to extend it to better mimic file writer. This more or less addresses the second variant of mentioned above sending to server on recording completion.

If you also want to send data as recording goes, you will have to put more effort and, probably, extend writer file more (possible, but makes no sense for me), or rather stop using AVI mux at all switching to sending some sort of half-processed content to server where it is combined into playable file and eventually stored.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my main problem is how do I skip the Avi Mux filter and get the raw data from the microphone?

Comment: Sounds like you have a question which is severely different from the one you asked.  I am guessing it is about accessing original data streamed through pipeline, such as `SampleCB` callback and Sample Grabber filter... You should probably ask it as a new question stepping back to original challenge.

Comment: Yea I thought that I can grab the avi data from Avi Mux but I saw all of these comments stating that I should lose Avi Mux

Answer (score 1):

As Roman already said, you should remove the AVI MUX from your graph. Just send the raw audio data you get from the microphone to the server. And mux the data on the server side to an AVI file.

AVI MUX and FileWriter are a special combination. As the AVI MUX not just outputs chunks of an AVI file, but calls a special interface to write to the file after the filter graph has been stopped!

Comment: How can I get the raw data from the microphone? using which filter?